# How to copy information entered into userform

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am trying to create an employee reprimand database by using an Excel userform. I want to be able to copy the information entered into the userform so the whole reprimand doesn't have to be retyped for a different employee with the same issue. I'm not sure how to go about coding this.

I've never coded with VBA before, so I am a true novice. The project has been pretty successful so far, but now I'm stuck. Sometimes we have multiple employees being written up for the same mishap, and I would like to have a button that copies the information that has been entered into the Userform so it doesn't all have to be re-typed. However, no matter how much searching I do on the internet, I can't find anything that quite solves my problem.

Ideally, I would like to have a "Copy" command button that duplicates the information in some of the textboxes, but not all of them. I would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: Create a button, in the ```onclick event``` put the data wherever it is going, then clear the name field, and whatever other fields you don't want copied.

Comment: If you're creating a *database*, **consider** using an actual RDBMS for that. Microsoft Access is a much better-suited tool for doing this.

Comment: My company currently uses an Access for this database, but I would prefer switching it to excel for multiple reasons. 1-I'm not very familiar with Access; 2-I've tried to create databases from scratch in Access and for whatever reason nothing makes sense in my head; 3-the database I currently use is Frankenstein'd from another database and doesn't always function correctly; 4-not many people in my company understand Access and since this would, ideally, be used by multiple employees I would prefer the database be in a program more people are familiar with.